# How to store sprite data in a VBO?

Tags: opengl, sprites

I'm planning on rendering many sprites in my games, but I am not sure which method of storing their data to use. I haven't tried all of them yet, but I want to see if I also have anything important missing. Right now my options are:

- Store information such as position, color, rotation, scale, and texIndex in a VBO, and then let the geometry shader output the triangles. (Not sure if possible)
- Compute the vertices for all sprites in the CPU and put it all into one VBO to draw. (Sounds like a waste of CPU time, especially in a game)
- Store repeated copies of the same four vertices in a VBO, and then use uniforms? (This is just an idea, I have no idea if it works or makes sense) Apparently I can just use instancing for this.

What design should I use to efficiently store sprite data? Do any of my ideas hold?

Edit: I would greatly appreciate if pseudocode could be provided for a solution, although certainly not necessary.

Comment: Third option sounds like instancing, you might want to look into that. I'm currently using option 1 i would like to know the answer too.